# Upload file in Node.js from React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

I want to upload file in node.js but with a especific path, i use multer in node.js, but i dont have idea to send the path from react, mi code is:

```
state = {
      selectedFile: null,
        }

fileSelectedHandler = event => {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
        });
    }
fileUploadHandler = () => {
        const fd = new FormData();
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        };
            fd.append('noren', this.state.selectedFile)
            axios.post('uploadFile', fd, config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("El archivo se subio exitosamente");
                }).catch((error) => {
            });
    }
```

and the code in node is the next:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/var/pruebas/'+type);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('noren')

uploadContr.uploadFile = upload, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('La ruta es: ', req.path)
    const file = req.file
    if (!file) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
        error.httpStatusCode = 400
        return next(error)
    }
    return res.send({status: 'ok'})
};
```

I try to send the path as a parameter in the axios with the following form:

```
fd.append('noren', this.state.selectedFile)
            axios.post('uploadFile', fd,{data:{path: this.props.path}} config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("El archivo se subio exitosamente");
                }).catch((error) => {
            });
```

or

```
fd.append('noren', this.state.selectedFile,this.props.path)
            axios.post('uploadFile', fd, config)
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("El archivo se subio exitosamente");
                }).catch((error) => {
            });
```

but the path is not send. I hope can help me

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536943/how-to-convert-blob-object-in-ejs-template/61539932#61539932](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536943/how-to-convert-blob-object-in-ejs-template/61539932#61539932)

Comment: I check this but my problem is how send the pat from react, I tried send in the Form Data but i don't have idea to receive in node, this is my problem

Comment: you don't send the path, you send the file name

Comment: I know, each user has a specific directory on the server, I want to send the path of the user's directory so that the file is saved there